# Can't change the user key bindings to open sublime in different browsers?

Tags: sublimetext3

Hey friends I've been using chrome for the development of my websites but know I wanna switch things up a bit. I read [this article](https://medium.com/@talialongname/sublime-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-in-browser-421688dcbd51)  on how to do it. I did this in the past for chrome and it worked. But when I paste:

```
[ 

 { “keys”: [ “ctrl+alt+v” ], “command”: “view_in_browser” },
 { “keys”: [ “ctrl+alt+f” ], “command”: “view_in_browser”, “args”: { “browser”: “firefox” } },
 { “keys”: [ “ctrl+alt+c” ], “command”: “view_in_browser”, “args”: { “browser”: “chrome” } },
 { “keys”: [ “ctrl+alt+i” ], “command”: “view_in_browser”, “args”: { “browser”: “iexplore” } },
 { “keys”: [ “ctrl+alt+s” ], “command”: “view_in_browser”, “args”: { “browser”: “safari” } }

]
```

in the key bindings user file I get this error?

```
Error trying to parse file: Expected value in Packages\User\Default
(Windows).sublime-keymap:3:4
```

Edit: I was told to turn the curly quotes into straight quotes. I did this and while it did fix the issue of saving the file, the error message did not show up. However I am not able to open Firefox with Ctrl + Alt + f?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this is not working for you is that your JSON is invalid; [JSON](https://json.org/) only allows for straight double quotes, but the JSON you pasted above is using curly quotes:

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark:

> - '...' and "…" are known as neutral, vertical, straight, typewriter, dumb, or ASCII quotation marks. The left and right marks are identical. These are found on typical English typewriters and computer keyboards, although they are sometimes automatically converted to the other type by software.
> - ‘…’ and “…” are known as typographic, curly, curved, book, or smart quotation marks. The beginning marks are commas raised to the top of the line and rotated 180 degrees. The ending marks are commas raised to the top of the line. Curved quotation marks are used mainly in manuscript, printing and typesetting.

As a result of this, Sublime's JSON parser (which is lenient in that it allows for extraneous trailing commas and comments that standard JSON disallows) doesn't understand the curly quotes, so it's not finding what it expects at line 3, column 4.

Replacing all of the double quote characters with straight quotes should solve the problem.

Comment: Didn't work. It did let me save it this time though, so it was able to parse. But I couldn't open firefox with Ctrl + Alt + f? Here's what it looks like

Comment: [
 
 { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+v" ], "command": "view_in_browser" },
 { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+f" ], "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "firefox" } },
 { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+c" ], "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "chrome" } },
 { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+i" ], "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "iexplore" } },
 { "keys": [ "ctrl+alt+s" ], "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "safari" } }
 
]

Comment: That may be a different issue; the one you asked about here was regarding the error message. Can you edit your question with further details about what's not working with this fix? For example, does it do nothing? Does it still open Chrome no matter what?

Comment: You should also include your package settings for this package as well.

Comment: My view in browser package? How do I do that?